# GBM multinomial distribution, how to use predict() to get predicted class?

Tags: r, prediction, categorical-data, multinomial, gbm

I am using the multinomial distribution from the `gbm` package in R.   When I use the `predict` function, I get a series of values:

```
5.086328 -4.738346 -8.492738 -5.980720 -4.351102 -4.738044 -3.220387 -4.732654
```

but I want to get the probability of each class occurring.  How do I recover the probabilities?  Thank You.

Comment: (There is no "GBM" package. The case of letters is important in R.) If you don't want to produce data then why not produce code that uses sample data from the help pages?

Comment: You've accepted an answer which was factually incorrect for the last 3.5 years. I gave you an answer which actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `?predict.gbm`, you'll see that there is a "type" parameter to the function. Try out `predict(<gbm object>, <new data>, type="response")`.

Comment: No, predict.gbm(..., type="response") is not implemented for multinomial, or indeed any distribution other than bernoulli or poisson.

Comment: Per @smci, currently the latest version of GBM is 2.1.1 released in May 2015, and `type="response"` is still not implemented. @smci's suggested use of `apply` below works, though.

Answer (score 10):

`predict.gbm(..., type='response')` is not implemented for multinomial, or indeed any distribution other than bernoulli or poisson.

So you have to find the most likely class (`apply(.., 1, which.max)` on the vector output from prediction), as [desertnaut wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454883/in-gbm-multinomial-dist-how-to-use-predict-to-get-categorical-output/29456904#29456904):

```
preds = predict(your_model, n.trees, newdata=...,type='response')

pred_class <- apply(preds, 1, which.max)
```

Just write a wrapper which accepts type='response' and returns this when it's a multinomial model.