# In gbm multinomial dist, how to use predict to get categorical output?

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-data, multinomial, gbm

My response is a categorical variable (some alphabets), so I used distribution='multinomial' when making the model, and now I want to predict the response and obtain the output in terms of these alphabets, instead of matrix of probabilities.

However in `predict(model, newdata, type='response')`, it gives probabilities, same as the result of `type='link'`.

Is there a way to obtain categorical outputs?

```
BST = gbm(V1~.,data=training,distribution='multinomial',n.trees=2000,interaction.depth=4,cv.folds=5,shrinkage=0.005)

predBST = predict(BST,newdata=test,type='response')
```

Comment: How about picking the response having the highest probability?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In `predict.gbm` documentation, it is mentioned:

> If type="response" then gbm converts back to the same scale as the
>   outcome. Currently the only effect this will have is returning
>   probabilities for bernoulli and expected counts for poisson. For the
>   other distributions "response" and "link" return the same.

What you should do, as Dominic suggests, is to pick the response with the highest probability from the resulting `predBST` matrix, by doing `apply(.., 1, which.max)` on the vector output from prediction.
Here is a code sample with the `iris` dataset:

```
library(gbm)

data(iris)

df <- iris[,-c(1)] # remove index

df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]  # shuffle

df.train <- df[1:100,]
df.test <- df[101:150,]

BST = gbm(Species~.,data=df.train,
         distribution='multinomial',
         n.trees=200,
         interaction.depth=4,
         #cv.folds=5,
         shrinkage=0.005)

predBST = predict(BST,n.trees=200, newdata=df.test,type='response')

p.predBST <- apply(predBST, 1, which.max)

> predBST[1:6,,]
     setosa versicolor  virginica
[1,] 0.89010862 0.05501921 0.05487217
[2,] 0.09370400 0.45616148 0.45013452
[3,] 0.05476228 0.05968445 0.88555327
[4,] 0.05452803 0.06006513 0.88540684
[5,] 0.05393377 0.06735331 0.87871292
[6,] 0.05416855 0.06548646 0.88034499

 > head(p.predBST)
 [1] 1 2 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: and to translate to class labels one could use: `colnames(predBST)[p.predBST]`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!